# Error in autorun script, RASP 3

Tags: raspbian, python, boot-issues, script, lxterminal

I need to run a script in lxterminal in boot. The unit is headless, just have a digital button to start the process in the code.
I already have a automatic pi user loggin and a .desktop created in autostart to open terminal and run the script like this:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Encoding=UTF-8
Name=PyServer
Exec=lxterminal -e "sudo python /home/pi/Desktop/programmer/start.py"
Icon=lxterminal
Type=Application
Categories=Utility;
```

The problem is, the script starts and send a error like:

```
   codes = os.listdir('./py_flasher')
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: './py_flasher'
```

(I need to check files in the directory)

But running it by hand inputs in terminal, it run properly.
It could be something like a OS process that not have beem started yet?

Comment: how do you know that the `.` directory is the same as when you run manually?

Comment: I ran the code from the same directory, it should be different? this method just returns the current path, right?

Comment: this question has been asked and answered many times ... it is not a Raspberry Pi question, so you asked in the wrong place ... it is a linux question

Comment: all right, i never worked with raspberry/linux before. Where can I find the resolution?

Comment: search `linux run script at boot` ... here is one hit https://www.golinuxcloud.com/run-script-at-startup-boot-without-cron-linux/

Comment: I followed the method in the link. There is some manner to keep the terminal open? I cant check if it is running properly.

Comment: print a status message to a log file ... examine the log file any time you like

Comment: I got deeper: checking the service status i receive that msg:
● run-at-startup.service - start-python-script Service
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/run-at-startup.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: activating (auto-restart) (Result: exit-code) since Mon 2021-06-21 17:57:26 -03; 6s ago
  Process: 7305 ExecStart=/usr/bin/python3 /home/pi/Desktop/esp_programmer/py_flasher.py (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
 Main PID: 7305 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
root@raspberrypi /h/p/D/esp_programmer#